# Select and Unselect all checkboxes

Tags: java, javascript, jquery

I'm not able to implement these things,In this page I want to do implement 3 things:

1> *By default Apple and Cat will be checked in this page.*
 2> *For Startall all the features will be checked and disabled.*
 3> *For Stopall, all the features will be disabled as well as default*(AC) value will be disabled.*

```
 <script type="text/javascript"> //This jquery is using for on selecting the checkbox,it will assign the text field of policyName and features
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $('.check').click(function(){
            $("#policyName").val('Start'); 
            $("#features").val('');
                    $(".check").each(function(){
                if($(this).prop('checked')){
                    $("#policyName").val($("#policyName").val() + $(this).val());   
                    $("#features").val($("#features").val() + $(this).data('name'));
                    }           
            });
         });
    });
    </script>
```

Here is my jsp page :

```
<div align="center" id="checkboxes">
<input type="checkbox" name="startall" data-name="Startall" class="check" id="check" value="all"> All &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="checkbox" name="stopall" data-name="Stopall" class="check" id="check" value="stopall"> STOPall &nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="checkbox" name="apple" data-name="Apple" class="check" id="check" value="a"> Apple &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="checkbox" name="ball" data-name="Ball" disabled="disabled" checked="checked"  id="check" value="b"> Ball 
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="checkbox" name="cat" data-name="Cat" class="check" id="check" value="a"> Cat &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="checkbox" name="dog" data-name="Dog" checked="checked" disabled="disabled"  id="check" value="d"> Dog 
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="checkbox" name="elephant" data-name="Elephant" disabled="disabled" checked="checked"  id="check" value="e"> 
    Elephant &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</div>
```

Any Assistance....will be apprciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

**ID** in your HTML should be **unique**.. Try using different id's or classes instead.. I have written the code using the name attribute  which is a slow selector..

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('[name="apple"], [name="cat"]').prop('checked', true);

$('[name="startall"]').on('click', function() {
    var $checkboxes = $('input[type="checkbox"]').not('[name="startall"], [name="stopall"]');
    if (this.checked) {
        $checkboxes.prop({
            checked: true,
            disabled: false
        });
        $('#textbox').val( $(this).attr('data-name'));
    }
    else{
         $checkboxes.prop({
            checked: false
        });
         $('#textbox').val('');
    }
});

$('[name="stopall"]').on('click', function() {
    var $checkboxes = $('input[type="checkbox"]').not('[name="startall"], [name="stopall"]');
    if (this.checked) {
        $checkboxes.prop({
            checked: false,
            disabled: true
        });
        $('#textbox').val( $(this).attr('data-name'));
    }
    else{
         $checkboxes.prop({
            disabled: false
        });
        $('#textbox').val('');
    }
});
```

});​

**[UPDATED DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/2mnem/3/)**

Comment: A big fat thanks for your quick reply;one more thing is that I'm using text box,now the condition is if the box selected,then the data-name will be shown,any inputs on this con text.

Comment: No problem at all :) , Where will the textbox's be shown.. Will it be a separate textbox for each item

Comment: There is single textbox,on selecting A,B,E it'll show "StartABE"(here Start is the Prefix) ,on selecting All->will show "StartAll" selecting Stop it'll show "StopAll"

Comment: If thats the case then call a function in the click event that will iterate thru all the checkboxes and populate the corresponding ones

Comment: Check the Updated Demo in the post.. I have added the functionality for stopall and startall..  Hope you can handle the part where each item is clicked individually

Comment: I have updated the code too... Just added a Textbox in HTML and populating the data attribute into it

Comment: thanks,just one thing:After selecting All or StopAll if I unselect All/StopAll it should retain it's default value(i,e. A and C)

Comment: For that we need to store the initial values in an array or object and use this to get the initial state..

Comment: sorry to call you,but if I want to select a single or double select box like Ball and Elephant,it should be in the textbox like: Ball or Elepahant or BallElephant...any clue