# Regarding selecting select box

Tags: java, javascript, jquery

I have put a question(with my answer) and one of active participant gave a brilliant answer ,here is that link: [SelectBox](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/2mnem/3/).

I have tried,and here is the link : [My Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12814312/select-and-unselect-all-checkboxes/12814465#comment17332587_12814465)

The answer will be more better if

- By Default value of Apple and Cat(which will be selected all time) will be shown in the textbox.
- Selecting any check box (except:start & stopall, whether it is single or double or triple),the corresponding checkboxes value should have to shown in the textbox,like Apple, or BallElephant or CatDogElephant.
- either startall or stopall will be selected at a time.

any inputs will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is the [Chosen jquery plugin](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) that looks like what you want.

Otherwise, you can make yout input field readonly and update its values with a js function when a checkbox is clicked.